# Função PhoneDailer com SerialPort

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estou implementando uma aplicação em c# que precisa fazer uma discagem automática. Pesquisando encontrei uma função PhoneDailer.Open que recebe em parâmetro o numero do telefone. Porem não sei o próximo passo. Segue código da função:

```
public async void TesteLigação(string number)
    {
            try
            {
                PhoneDialer.Open(number);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException anEx)
            {
                // Number was null or white space
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
            {
                // Phone Dialer is not supported on this device.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Other error has occurred.
            }
    }
```

Executando apenas assim ele dá o seguinte erro:

> {"This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation."}

Comment: Verificou se a versão da biblioteca é suportada pela versão em que você está compilando a aplicação?

Comment: está executando em qual plataforma? Android, iOS?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é sim

Comment: @RicardoPontual Estou fazendo em c#, é um executável que só tende a ter essa função.

Comment: Bruno, a validação do suporte depende do target, Android é um, iOs e Windows tem outros, veja o código

Comment: Bom dia Ricardo, desculpe a demora para responder. Bom, pelo o que eu sei, estou fazendo para windows. A proposta é ter uma página de clientes onde ao clicar no cliente, a aplicação irá se comunicar diretamente com a central telefonica realizando uma ligação automática para o cliente.